# No module named 'newspaper'

Tags: installation, newspaper3k

I have installed "newspaper3k" both on the command line and onside the jupyter notebook. Both clearly say the package is installed. But when I sue import, it says the No Module named "newspaper".

It works on colab but not my local kernel (win 10, pyhton3).

Comment: Try installing from a cell in your notebook using `%conda install newspaper3k` if you are using Anaconda/conda on your system at all. Then try testing it worked with `from newspaper import Article`. If you are only using pip, try `%pip install newspaper3k` **in a cell in your notebook**. If you aren't familiar with these newer magic commands, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

Which python version you used while installing module and while running the code, it should be same.

1. Check if it is modules is present under Python{version}/lib. If not
2. try installing with the same python you are using try again.
3. If not there may be environment variable issue, set the same python version in ev